# django order_by("datetime") does not work

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-models

I am trying to get all objects off `Chat` distinct by the fields `phone_number (CharField)` and `agent (ForeignKey)` and order by `datetime DateTimeUTCField(default=datetime.now)`

```py
chats = self.get_queryset().order_by('phone_number', "agent","-datetime").distinct("phone_number", "agent")
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.datetime)
```

but when I see the order of the chats, the chats are not sorted by datetime

```
2024-02-12 14:12:29.352192
2024-02-12 16:14:36.196964
2024-02-12 14:20:26.696088
2024-02-12 14:16:36.225550
2024-02-12 17:25:45.896345
2024-02-12 17:35:58.424937
2024-02-12 15:07:23.808822
2024-02-12 16:14:37.775311
2024-02-12 14:19:28.939897
2024-02-12 16:14:34.493954
2024-02-12 16:41:08.697777
```

I think it is because I have also ordered by `phone_number` and `agent`, but if I remove them

```py
chats = self.get_queryset().order_by("datetime").distinct("phone_number", "agent")
            
for chat in chats:
    print(chat.datetime)
```

or order by datetime after the distinct:

```py
chats = self.get_queryset().order_by('phone_number', "agent").distinct("phone_number", "agent")
            
for chat in chats.order_by("-datetime"):
    print(chat.datetime)
```

Django raises this error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("lolo_agents_chat"."phone_number", "lolo...
```

Here's the `Chat` model

```py
class Chat(m.Model):
    agent = m.ForeignKey(
        Agent, on_delete=m.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    phone_number = m.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = DateTimeUTCField(default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: First you have to order by all the columns mentioned in the distinct on() and then you can order by other columns, like your date time column

Comment: Like what @FrankHeikens said, so "phone_number" and "agent" take precedence over "datetime".

Comment: Does not work if I sort by datetime after the distinct

Comment: `does not work` is not an error message. And without some example data and the SQL you execute, it's going to be very hard to help you.

Comment: I already edit the post with more details , but if sort after the distict, it django raises `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`